# open URL in google chrome with Android device

Tags: c#, android, ios, google-chrome

What is the proper URL syntax to open a link in google chrome when using an Android device? "googlechrome://www...." seems to work fine on ios but not on Android. 
When using this method in android, google chrome opens automatically but stays on the home page and doesn't go to the link
IMPORTANT EDIT: I am using C# and not Java

Comment: you can specify google chrome package name `com.android.chrome` while opening url.

Comment: Can you explain more please?

Comment: in android we can specify package name to open specific app using Intent `Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.chrome");`
not sure if it is possible if c# as well.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but sadly it's not

Answer (score 1):

To open a website from your app, you have to the following :

```
String url = "https://www.example.com";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: No, I want to force the app to use google chrome as a browser, and I'm using c#. The only piece of code that I found to do that is with Application.OpenURL(@"googlechrome://www...")) or Process.Start(). It works fine on the desktop but when using android there is onnly an empty tab that opens